# Redefining "and" not working in apacite

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I want to use apacite with the modification that "&" before the last author should be replaced by "and".

According to the [apacite pacakge documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite?lang=en) (Ch. 6), this should be accomplished by redefining \BBAA, \BBAB and \BAnd to use the string "and".

I tried it with the following example, which does not work:

my.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}
\renewcommand{\BBAB}{and}
\renewcommand{\BAnd}{and}

\begin{document}
Test \cite{one} test \cite{two} test \cite{three}

\bibliography{my}
\end{document}
```

my.bib:

```
@inproceedings{one,
  title={Counting One},
  author={John One},
  year={2017}
}
@inproceedings{two,
  title={Counting Two},
  author={John One and Mary Two},
  year={2017}
}
@inproceedings{three,
  title={Counting Three},
  author={John One and Mary Two and Tom Three},
  year={2017}
}
```

The result is still:

[image: compiled output of example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you have to delay the redefinition, at least this seems to work for me

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\BBAA}{and}
  \renewcommand{\BBAB}{and}
  \renewcommand{\BAnd}{and}
}
```

have not investigated further

Comment: The `apacite.sty` package inputs `english.apc` (or other language related file) at begin document and such files reset the `\B...` macros to the default `\&`.